# jenkins Variables not showing up in shell command

Tags: jenkins, groovy, environment-variables, multibranch-pipeline

I am trying to execute a shell command in my jenkinsfile but the variables that i set arent showing up in the shell command I am trying to execute. here is my code:

```
def branchName = BRANCH_NAME
def newBranchName = branch name.split('/')[1]

pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage ('build') {
            steps {
                sh 'docker build -t 771225398400.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/nics/em-api:$newBranchName .'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This outputs

```
docker build -t 771225398400.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/nics/em-api: .
```

However, When I simply run a "println($newBranchName)", the correct String  is printed. Any clue as to why the variables dont appear? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use double quote but single quote around your sh script. [More detail](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#string-interpolation)

```
sh "docker build -t 771225398400.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/nics/em-api:$newBranchName ."
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is:

```
    sh '''
    docker build -t 771225398400.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/nics/em-api:$newBranchName .
    '''
```